How to use secrets in Azure DevOps Powershell script task
I have a secret in a Azure keyvault which basically stores 1 command az login --service-principal -u ...
I am trying to call this secret in a simple Powershell Task but when I run the pipeline every time it appears as masked with output ***. It doesn't need to be shown it just needs to do what it is meant to
Azure DevOps pipeline is classic ( cannot be YAML for now)
Powershell Task is file path one (cannot be inline as script passes 20000 chars)

"it just needs to do what it is meant to" - well, what is it meant to do, and what is it currently doing?

well the command is az login --spn... so it needs to login then it shows bunch of subscriptions it has access to which means is worked but right now this is not happening, i just get "***"

Can you share the relevant portions of the script and the task definition? Eg. any place where you reference the secret

I have been testing with a small sample script of just 2 lines
$(azCreds)
az account show
If this is inline, it works!! but since i need to use file path, there is does not. I have tried passing the secret as an argument, an environment variable, but still "***"


I have a secret in a Azure keyvault which basically stores 1 command az login --service-principal -u ...

Azure Key Vault should be used to store sensitive information, not logic of any kind. Consider creating secrets for the user name, password and tenant ID instead of storing the whole az login... command.
Another alternative would be to use an Azure service connection for the service principal.

I am trying to call this secret in a simple Powershell Task but when I run the pipeline every time it appears as masked with output ***

Secret variables are encrypted variables that you can use in pipelines without exposing their value, i.e. Azure Pipelines makes an effort to mask secrets when emitting data to pipeline logs.
Please note that the recommended ways to set secret variables are in the UI, in a variable group, and in a variable group from Azure Key Vault. You can also set secret variables in a script with a logging command but this isn't recommended since anyone who can access your pipeline can also see the secret.
See Set secret variables for more details.

So if I store username, pswd, etc. In key vault and call them in script it'll work? Why isn't what I am doing working? If I call the variable in inline script, it works! But not when I pass it as an argument or environment variable in case of file path

Hi @MuditBalooja, Thanks for the update. May I know what you meant by If I call the variable in inline script, it works? Did you linked the secrets in your Key Vault with your pipelines Library and call the secret variable in inline script like Write-Host $(someKVSecret)?

Can you please share your PowerShell script in the original post and let us know how your retrieved the Key Vault secret value to run az login? Was it using a pipelines Library linked with your Key Vault? By the way, was your pipeline running on a Microsoft-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent?

So if I store username, pswd, etc. In key vault and call them in script it'll work? - how are you retrieving the secrets? If you use an AzureKeyVault task or a variable group linked to a KeyVault secrets will be available in the pipeline. See the last link in my answer for more details.

Hi Rui you were right, instead of storing the whole command I just stored username, pswd, tenant and it worked! But my question still remains on why seperate behaviour of inline vs file path. I use AzureKey Vault task to download all secrets from keyvault and pass it as an argument for ps script to use

@MuditBalooja please edit your question and include the relevant code, i.e. both the AzureKeyVault and the Powershell tasks.
